# Querying failed unit tests from TFS-SDK?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, tfs-sdk

Given a TFS build detail (IBuildDetail) with `.Status` of `PartialSuccess`, and `.TestStatus` of `Failed`  how might I go about retrieving the list of tests (MSTest) that have failed on that build?

I have a working sandbox in which I can contact TFS via the SDK and retrieve the latest PartialSuccess build, but can't seem to find which service might have this unit test data and how I might go about querying it.

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3279.aspx) article is a great resource, actually it was the only one I had found available when I was searching something similar.
In general you need access to `ITestManagementService`.
Given you already have connection to a `teamProjectCollection` and a `buildDetail`, something like this should work out for you :

```
var tstService = (ITestManagementService)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
ITestManagementTeamProject testManagementTeamProject = tstService.GetTeamProject(buildDetail.TeamProject);

IEnumerable<ITestRun> testRuns =  testManagementTeamProject.TestRuns.ByBuild(buildDetail.Uri);

foreach (var testRun in testRuns)
{
    ITestCaseResultCollection testcases = testRun.QueryResultsByOutcome(TestOutcome.Failed);
    foreach (var testcase in testcases)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestCase ID: " + testcase.TestCaseId);
        Console.WriteLine("TestCase Title: " + testcase.TestCaseTitle);
        Console.WriteLine("Error Message: " + testcase.ErrorMessage);                  
    }
}
```

(This code is basically a copy from the article above, it is work by [Anuj Chaudhary](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/anujchaudhary/))
 Remember to add "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client" in your ref list.

Comment: Had to add a couple more assembly references, but this was indeed the answer. Thanks!